# Вставить с БД уникальные значения

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть json объект вида `[{"color":"red"}, {"color":"blue"}, {"color":"red"},...]`. Есть таблица с колонкой color. Как мне вставить, с помощью sql, в эту таблицу значения словарей так, чтобы они не повторялись? То есть в конце в таблице должны быть только две записи `"red"` и `"blue"`. БД Postgres.

Comment: зависит от структуры таблицы. Лучше всего сделать колонку уникальной и вставлять данные с ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING хотя не помешало бы отфильтровать данные и заранее с помощью того языка где вы этот json разбираете, что бы не создавать лишнюю нагрузку на БД

Comment: Дело в том, что для моей задачи этот json нельзя отфильтровать до БД, потому что данные из него пойдут еще и в другие таблицы и мне он нужен целый.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Трансформировать](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) массив JSON в набор записей, затем посчитать `distinct`:

```
select distinct r->>'color' 
from json_array_elements('[{"color":"red"}, {"color":"blue"}, {"color":"red"}]') as r;
```

Для вставки в табличку дописать соответствующий `insert`

```
insert into tablename (color)
select distinct r->>'color' 
from json_array_elements('[{"color":"red"}, {"color":"blue"}, {"color":"red"}]') as r;
```

Так же можно использовать часть [`on conflict`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html) запроса `insert` если есть подходящее уникальное ограничение.

Comment: я забыл про distinct, спасибо